# Jackson mapper.readValue() массив внутри json

Tags: java, json, jackson

Использовал Jackson для создания объектов на базе json примерно так

```
public class User {
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonSetter("first_name")
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    JsonNode usersGetResult = "{\"id\":100,\"first_name\":\"Александра\"}"
    User user = mapper.readValue(usersGetResult.toString(), User.class);
}
```

И все было хорошо, до одного момента. В json строках появились массивы:

```
{"id":100,"first_name":"Александра","city":{"id":1,"title":"Москва"}}
```

Подскажите реализацию, чтоб в объект user еще и массивы добавлялись. Конкретно нужно из этого массива например только "Москва" в переменную city.

Уже все облазил, никак не доходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе User

```
@JsonProperty("city")
private City city

@JsonSetter("city")
public void setCity(City) {
 this.city = city;
}

public class City {
 private Integer id;
 private String title;

 //seters and getters

}
```

Если же нужен массив из City, то надо писать так

```
private City[] cities
```

Comment: @Andrey подскажите пожалуйста а если JSON приходит внутри </tml><body>[{"userId": 10,"id": 100}]</body></html>, я конечно костыль написал но хочу все сделать правильно